# VBA to refresh Pivots

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am using code to refresh Pivots and it works, but im getting stuck with the error handler, it gives me:

> object variable with block variable not set

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivots()

On Error GoTo Errhandler

  Dim pivotTable As pivotTable
  For Each pivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    pivotTable.RefreshTable
  Next

Errhandler:

     MsgBox "Error Refreshing " & pivotTable.Name

MsgBox "All Pivots Refreshed"

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only want to display the error message if there is an error. Additionally, you may wish to check if the error happened while the pivotTable object was assigned:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivots()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
ErrHandler:
    If err Then
        If Not pt Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Error Refreshing " & pt.Name
        Else
            MsgBox "Unexpected error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "All Pivots Refreshed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I renamed your `pivotTable` variable to `pt` - it's not great practice to use reserved words as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The error "object variable with block variable not set" is thrown, because `pivotTable.Name` is not declared after the `For Each pivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables` loop.

This variable is assigned to a value only within that loop. The `Exit Sub` before the error handler is a best practice in VBA:

```
Sub RefreshAllPivots()

    On Error GoTo Errhandler

    Dim pivotTable As pivotTable
    For Each pivotTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pivotTable.RefreshTable
        Debug.Print pivotTable.Name
    Next

    MsgBox "All Pivots Refreshed"
    Exit Sub

Errhandler:        
    MsgBox "Error Refreshing " & pivotTable.Name

End Sub
```